# HTML form drop down select issue

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've got a login form which I'm trying to simplify. It all worked when you manually inputted your username and password. Now I am wanting a drop down for the username box from the MySql database.

This is the code that I have put into the form and it drops down and shows all the users but when you select it, put the password in and click login it doesn't pass the username.

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password.'); 
mysql_select_db('database');

$sql = "SELECT username FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<select username='sub1'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))   {
echo"<option value'" . $row['username'] ."'>" . $row['username'] ."</option>"; } echo "</select>";?>
```

Any Ideas Anyone

Thanks

Comment: `<select username='sub1'>` it doesn't work that way, use `name`

Comment: Besides the fact that you put all your users in a select box, `echo "<select username='sub1'>";` << what is that?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Actually a name tag would be more sufficient than a value tag.

Comment: @Daan I realized that before your comment and have edited it. @ Tom: Selects have name not what you have now, my mistake. `<option value="xxx">` options have value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tom, always check your generated HTML to investigate errors.

Change your code to:

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password.'); 
mysql_select_db('database');

$sql = "SELECT username FROM users";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<select name='username'>"; // Note name attribute
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))   {
  echo "<option value='" . $row['username'] ."'>" . $row['username'] ."</option>"; // Note `=` sign after value
 } 
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: Awsome thanks for your help... didn't work initially but relised that i needed to change something in another php file aswell

Answer (score 0):

replace your code with this:

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password.'); 
mysql_select_db('database');

$sql = "SELECT username FROM users";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<select name='sub1'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
echo "<option value='" . $row['username'] ."'>" . $row['username'] ."</option>"; 
} 
echo "</select>";
?>
```